# MIDI processor passthru AudioUnit doesn't receive MIDI events

Tags: ios, swift, midi, auv3, augraph

I'm trying to create a simple pure MIDI Audio Unit (AUv3) that could act as a pipe between for example an `AVMusicTrack` (played by an `AVAudioSequencer`) and an `AVAudioUnitSampler`.

I used the default audio extension template generated by XCode 13.2.1 and modified just a few things:

- My audio unit has type `kAudioUnitType_MIDIProcessor` (`aumi`), from what I read it's the right candidate and the only one I can connect to a sampler (else the app will crash with the `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: graphNodeSrc->IsMIDIProcessorNode()` message. (Maybe I'm missing something here btw?)
- I overrode `handleMIDIEvent()` function in my AU's DSP Kernel just to print something when I receive MIDI events:

```
    void handleMIDIEvent(const AUMIDIEvent &midiEvent) override {
        cout << "MIDI Event" << endl;
    }
```

- I declared a `MIDIOutputNames` properly

My goal is to follow the MIDI playing context from this AU, and edit some note messages depending on the context.

My host provides `AUMIDIOutputEventBlock`, `AUHostTransportStateBlock` and `AUHostMusicalContextBlock` so that the AU can read the state and context and output MIDI to the host.

If I make my AU a `kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice` (`aumu`), I do receive note events from the music track (even if I cannot connect my AU to the sampler as it's not a MIDI processor). But with a MIDI processor, I don't. Any clue why this is?